# Subtract txt file

Tags: batch-file, substring

I have a text file, and I want to subtract first 8 char and save as a new file.

How can I do it?

my file asd contains:

```
TŕÓkm»ék6833
```

Edit v1:

I connected to files by:

```
COPY wIV.txt+secretkey.txt asd.txt
```

Then I trying to put asd.txt as a variable.

```
set /p VAR1=<asd.txt
```

Now I want to take out first 8 chars:

```
@echo %VAR1:~0,7%
```

and save to file.

I don't know its a good subtract. and I have a problem to save it to other .txt file.

Edit v2

I want to use a new file as input data to the java application. and from:

```
TŕÓkm»ék6833
```

I need

```
TŕÓkm»ék
```

Edit v3

When I open asd.txt, it reads as it contains 2 lines of the text.
For example:

```
TŕÓkm»ék
| <- this is my cursor.
```

```
TŕÓkm»ék| <- I need to cursor to be here.
```

Comment: Note: `%VAR1:~0,7%` is NOT "from Pos0 to Pos7", but "from Pos0, Length7". To write the first eight chars into a file: `(echo %VAR1:~0,8%)>file.txt`

Comment: To remove the first eight characters, you'd use `%VAR1:~8%`. Before you just do that, are you sure that those first characters aren't because you're copying a file with a BOM, like UTF-32 BE for instance. You may want to check the files encoding first, and let us know what they are. If it is an encoding issue, there may be a better way of retrieving your required text string instead of using a basic `COPY` command.

Comment: Regardless, I'd still suggest that this is a BOM, and you're essentially trying to export that BOM to the beginning of a new file, or you're trying to remove the BOM from the required string, saving just that string to the new file. "I want to take out first 8 chars" is not clear, you either want to save ```TŕÓkm»ék```, or ```6833``` to the new file. There is an [edit] button you can use to ensure that your question is understandable. Either the comment from Stephan is what you need, or the comment from myself.

Comment: @Compo I edited it. and I can also tell you. It's my key to decrypt a DES encryption. after adding this numbers to send it over from client and server. and yes, I only want to save TŕÓkm»ék  as a file.

Comment: @Stephan my bad. I corrected it.

Comment: I don't understand the `Edit v3` part. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Compo IT`s exactly what I needed. <3 now it's working fantastic.

Comment: This seems to be turning into a guessing game, unfortunately. Is the part to be removed, `"6833"`, always 4 characters long? Is it the part that is added by  "secretkey.txt"? If it is, doesn't "wIV.txt" contain the text that you want to extract? Is it that  "wIV.txt" is unicode and "secretkey.txt" ANSI?

Comment: wIV.txt will be always 8 chars, secretkey.txt can be even 1 char, doesn't matter. after merging this, this is sending away to disk K: , and must be subtracted on disk K:. something like simulation transmission. and that's must be secured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your now clarified question and requirements:

```sh
COPY "wIV.txt" + "secretkey.txt" "asd.txt"
SET /P "VAR1=" 0< "asd.txt"
SET /P "=%VAR1:~,8%" 0< NUL 1> "newfile.txt"
```